# APK package installer unresponsive before installing?

Tags: installation, package, delay, freeze, pause

Hi,
I'm working with android app (not yet in play store) and have trouble with APK install delay.
E.g.
On selecting APK hyperlink, Then selecting 'Package installer'
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aQxl.png)

Install dialog just sits for 5 to 10+ seconds unresponsive. Like perhaps package isn't installing.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsBzB.png)

apk size is ~16mb
Does anyone else have different experience with delay time?
E.g If installing apk not from app store?

---

If selecting "install package" link, then quickly opening web browser, it appears to kickstart apk install sooner.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsoB3.png)

P.s
-- thankyou stack overflow & community.